# React-Native-Router-Flux background Image

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-router-flux

I got a Problem with my App right now.

react-native version:  0.51

react-native-router-flux version: 4.0.0-beta.27

In my Android Version everything works fine. 
On IOS my Background Image is not displayed, it is only displayed on the first Layer of the nesting.

The code for the scene and routers is something like this :

```
<Wallpaper>
 <Router sceneStyle={{backgorundColor:'transparent'}}>
  <Overlay>
   <Scene key='root'>

    <Tabs>
         ... tabs 
    </Tabs

    <Scene key ='login' component= {Login}/>
   </Scene>
   <Scene key='Messagebar' component={Messagebar}/>
  </Overlay>
 <Router>
</Wallpaper>
```

On the root scene level the image is visable, on the tabs the background is black.

Anyone wo could help mit with this problem?

The Wallpaper Component is just a ImageBackground from the react-native package

something like this:

```
<ImageBackground>
 <View>
  ... Statusbar stylings
 </View>
 {this.props.children}
</ImageBackground>
```

regards,

Flo